# Kubernetes 1.9 dashboard v1.10.0 log in screen

Tags: kubernetes, elastic-stack, graylog

How to "remove" token from kubernetes dashboard and get the dashboard log in screen again?
Thanks in advance
LC

Answer (score 0):

In upper-right part of Kubernetes Dashboard, you have
[Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNjxt.png)  button
 which you click and logout, then you will get sign in page

Comment: It's missing on dashboard screen, only "+CREATE" and no ControlPanel button.

Comment: please press login icon on the right side of +CREATE and you will see Logout